# What am I doing wrong here if(isset($_GET['Confirm']))?

Tags: php

My Get confirm isn't triggering the query? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

url: `http://www.example.co.uk/registerinterest.php?productid=125&confirm=Confirm`

```
<div class="confirminterest">
     <form action="registerinterest.php?productid=' . $productid . '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input name="confirm" type="submit" id="confirm" value="Confirm" />
     <input name="cancel" type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel" /></form>
   </div>

 if (isset($_GET['Confirm'])) {
         $addinterest = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tm_credits_spent (fk_customer_id, fk_product_id, int_credits_spent) VALUES('$pid','$productid','$adminfee')") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Your URL contains `GET` parameters, but your form uses `POST`.  Does `INSERT` run when you go to that URL, or when the form is `POST`ed?

Comment: No. Even when I submit the url above nothing is inserted into the DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for GET data when your form uses the POST method. Since you are inserting data into a database, POST is correct, so replace `$_GET` with `$_POST`.

You are also looking for `Confirm` when your button is named `confirm`. PHP is case sensitive, so replace that too.

```
$_POST['confirm']
```

---

You also appear to be at risk of [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thank you, changed that, but still not triggering :-(

I haven't added the security yet.

Comment: @user1224032 — How do you know it isn't triggering? Do you have debug data to force output when it does? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: @user1224032 — Security is not something that you add later, you build it in from the start (especially when, if done sanely, database security with PHP comes from not using the `mysql_query` function at all). Otherwise it is too easy to miss a bit when you go back to add it.

Comment: I'm checking the mysql database.

I'm trying to not confuse it with security, as you can probably tell Im new. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Out of interest, What would be the alternative to mysql_query?

Comment: There are a number of methods behind the link in my answer. PDO is the usual choice.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my own answer as the others are missing that the name of your input is "confirm", not "Confirm" (that's its value).

So you must check `isset()` for `$_POST['confirm']`, not `$_POST['Confirm']` or `$_GET['confirm']`.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is sending POSTdata, not GET. Either change the form's method, or check for `$_POST['confirm']`.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the method to be post. Try with $_POST['Confirm'];

Answer (score 0):

In both your `GET` string, and your form (which uses `POST`), the field is `"confirm"`, not `"Confirm"`.  Note the lower case `'c'`.

Try: `if (isset($_GET['confirm'])) {` (or `if (isset($_POST['confirm'])) {`).

Answer (score -1):

you are using php variable in html may be that's the issue
replace this;

```
<form action="registerinterest.php?productid=' . $productid . '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

with

```
<form action="registerinterest.php?productid=' .<?php $productid ?>. '" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and yes use `$_POST['confirm']` for condition.